# How do I make an IF statement that compares 2 integers assigned to 2 string variables in 1 class then execute the code in another class in Java?

Tags: java, class, if-statement

I have these 2 string variables, `Hulk` and `Thing`, `Hulk` has a strength of `10` and `Thing` has a strength of `53`, they both fight (the IF statement) where the higher integer strength wins.

Then Hulk received a powerup boosting his strength to 110, now both fight again. The winner's name is printed on the screen both times.

I have 2 classes (a `main class` and a `supporting one`). The IF statement of my supporting class is attached along with my `getStrength()` method (if anymore code is needed let me know).

I am getting an **`error`** where is says: `if (name1.getStrength() > name2.getStrength()) ;` the error is that `getStrength()` isn't defined for string where `name1` and `name2` are.

Also, after solving this, how do I call this `subroutine` in my `main class`?
Thanks in advance!

**IF Statement:**

```
if (name1.getStrength() > name2.getStrength())
{
    System.out.println(name1 + " Wins!");
}
else {
    System.out.println(name2 + " Wins!");
}
```

**getStrength method:**

```
int getStrength() {
    return this.strength;
}
```

Comment: Hulk and Thing should not be Strings, they should be instances of "Creature", which has a variable strength (which should be an int)

Comment: Ahh ..I resolved the same issue for some guy this morning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the characters as objects of class that has properties like name, strength, etc.

Then this thing should work : `if (Hulk.getStrength() > Thing.getStrength())`

Comment: Almost there! When I compile the code and run it, the strings printed should be 'Hulk' and 'Thing' but it shows: SuperHero@6d06d69c Wins! SuperHero@7852e922 has received a powerup of 100 SuperHero@7852e922 Wins! ; It's not passing the strings for some reason :/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should read about java first steps.
But in your app, you should create class which is representing your fighters and in this class create methods which get the strength from it, i.e.:

```
public class Fighter {
    private String name;
    private int strenght;

    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }
}
```

of course you need to create constructor or other setters/getters in this class. Then you can create objects, i.e.:

```
Fighter hulk = new Fighter(); 
Fighter thing = new Fighter(); 
// use constructor or setters to set strength and name
```

Now you can call method from class Fighter:

```
if(hulk.getStrength() > thing.getStrength()) {
    // your code
}
```

Your error is because you were trying to call `getStrength()` method on object of `String` type. The best way is to create your own type.

Comment: Almost there! When I compile the code and run it, the strings printed should be 'Hulk' and 'Thing' but it shows: SuperHero@6d06d69c Wins!
SuperHero@7852e922 has received a powerup of 100
SuperHero@7852e922 Wins!  ;   It's not passing the strings for some reason :/

Comment: Becouse `SuperHero@6d06d69c` is String representation of your object, not the name of it. In your `SuperHero` class you need  to place name (or other variable of String type) like I do in example. Use setter or constructor to set it, and then use getter in `System.out.println` method: `System.out.println(hulk.getName());`

Comment: But I haven't defined a getName() method, this is my code for passing the name as String: public class SuperHero 
{
 String name;
 int strength = 10;
 public int getStrength() {
  
  return this.strength;
 }
 
 public SuperHero(String name) {
  
  this.name = name;

 }

Comment: You have `name` attribute in your class, so define method to get that attribute, and use it.